# Using Sed with regular expression to save results into a variable

Tags: bash

What I'm trying to do is take user input as a string and parse a section of the string. The results from my regex I want to save into a new variable. Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
downloadUrl="$1"
pythonFile=echo $downloadUrl | sed '/Python-[\d+.]+tgz/'
echo "$downloadUrl"
echo "$pythonFile"
```

And here is my result.

```
sed: 1: "/Python-[\d+.]+tgz/": command expected
```

Comment: You need to put `$(...)` around the `echo ...|sed ...` command. Also, your shebang is broken and your variables could use some quoting. May I recommend using http://www.shellcheck.net ?

Comment: Also, shebang is wrong: it should be `#!`, not `!#`

Comment: And finally, unless you specifically require the shell to parse `$downloadUrl` and `$pythonFile` into tokens and perform wildcard expansion on them, you should quote these variables.  `echo "$downloadUrl"` and `echo "$pythonFile"` with double quotes around the variable interpolations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to run the commands in `$()` to get command substitution. Use:

```
pythonFile=$(echo $downloadUrl | sed '/Python-[\d+.]+tgz/')
```

See [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`sed '/Python-[\d+.]+tgz/'` is incorrect since you need to have a sed command like `p` and anyway it is only searching not really extracting part of input text.

You can use `grep -oP`

```
pythonFile$(grep -oP '/Python-[\d+.]+tgz/' <<< "$downloadUrl")
```

Or without `-P`

```
pythonFile$(grep -o '/Python-[0-9+.]\+tgz/' <<< "$downloadUrl")
```